# Is it possible to continuously play music on a website while switching to other pages on html?

Tags: html

I'm not sure if my question was clear or not (since I'm new to web development) but what I'm trying to say is:

I have this HTML line,

```
<embed src="Music/Disfigure%20-%20Blank.mp3" autostart="true" loop="true"
width="2" height="0">
```

When I view my website, the music starts playing as it should, but when I switch to another page, it starts from the beginning again. How can I keep it from restarting when I switch to a different page?

Comment: Not sure why the hate, it's a decent question.

Comment: The question itself is valid, but so is the hatred for websites that auto play music.  If you do this, you are ensuring I will never visit your site again.  Just some friendly feedback.

Comment: The answers have mentioned a few specifics, but look into Single Page Applications (SPA).  It's what you want.

Comment: Votes should be based on the validity of a question, not your preference. For all you know this could be a site where you pick a song to play and the desired result is that it continues as you browse.

Comment: I didn't downvote it, I was addressing the "hate" portion of your comment. :)  But you make a good point, though I think your scenario is unlikely in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but its a little more complex than you might think. In order for the music to continuously play, the site needs to be setup in a manner where navigation causes the same page to update rather than loading a new page. One way to do this is with AJAX.

You can read more about AJAX here: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

> **AJAX is a developer's dream, because you can:**
>
> - Update a web page without reloading the page
> - Request data from a server - after the page has loaded
> - Receive data from a server - after the page has loaded
> - Send data to a server - in the background

The basic theory is that you simply grab the content from the new page, and replace the content on the current page. This way the user never actually leaves the page so the music that is playing will continue to play. The reason it restarts when going to a new page is because the browser is having to reload everything when you change pages.

**Barba.js** is a great way to get up and running fast with AJAX. You can also add in great animations with it as well.
http://barbajs.org/

Comment: Thank you very much for this valuable information.

Answer (score 1):

This wouldn't be possible with just HTML. However if you structure the page such that sections are loaded dynamically using javascript via ajax or a library like: [SPFjs](https://youtube.github.io/spfjs/). Then you could have the music playing on the base page and change the content around that. This way the part of the page playing the music is never unloaded.

The only reason this isn't possible is going to a different page completely unloads the previous so the music would also be unloaded.